# Comparison between the $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ norms

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I am trying to prove that for $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}||x||_1 \le ||x||_2 \le ||x||_1$$  So far I have successfully proven that $||x||_2 \le ||x||_1$, which was fairly easy.  I took the square of both norms and used that to show that $||x||_2^2 \le ||x||_1^2$.  The needed result then follows easily.

Where I am getting stuck is in proving that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}||x||_1 \le ||x||_2$.  I took the square of both norms again, which results in $$(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}||x||_1)^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^2+\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i \neq j}|x_i||x_j|$$ and $$(||x||_2)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^2$$

My next step was to prove that $\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i \neq j}|x_i||x_j|$ must be less than the difference between $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|$, meaning that $$\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i \neq j}|x_i||x_j| \le \frac{n-1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|$$ Which is where I am now stuck.  Is there some identity that I am missing here that will make this easier?

Comment: Not an identity, but the Cauchy-Bun'akovskij-Schwarz inequality makes it easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the so-called $1$-trick (a special application of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality):

$$||x||_1^2 = \left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right)^2 = \left( \sum_{i=1}^n 1 \times x_i \right)^2 \le \left( \sum_{i=1}^n 1^2 \right) \left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i ^2 \right) = n \times ||x||_2 ^2$$

Where $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a sequence (in some order)  of $n^2$ terms that contains of each of $\{|x_1|, |x_2|,\ldots, |x_n|\}$ repeated $n$ times.  We now use the [rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality) on the below sum with $n^2$ summands, to draw the red conclusion:

$$\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}||x||_1\right)^2=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{(i,j)} |x_i||x_j|{\color{red} \le}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{(i,j)} |x_i||x_i|=\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^2$$